# How to add multiple fetching data in single spinner using array adapter

Tags: android-studio

My code:

Added data in array adapter but last data only comming how to add all the data in spinner using arrayadapter

```
while (rs.next()) {
                int_EMP_ID = rs.getInt("EmpID");
                str_EMP_Name = rs.getString("EmployeeName");




                int User_ID_List[] = {int_EMP_ID};
                String User_name_List[] = {str_EMP_Name};

                for (int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
                    // Step 2: Create and fill an ArrayAdapter with a bunch of "State" objects
                    ArrayAdapter<Employee> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Employee>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Employee[]{
                            new Employee(User_ID_List[i], User_name_List[i]),
                            new Employee(User_ID_List[i], User_name_List[i])
                    });
                }
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

```
<string-array name="array_name">
<item>Array Item One</item>
<item>Array Item Two</item>
<item>Array Item Three</item>
</string-array>
```

in your layout file.

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/array_name"
    />
```

Comment: exactly am getting more than 15 values from the SQL server so need to add array adapter but I got the last values on the spinner                                  ArrayAdapter<Employee> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Employee>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Employee[]{
                            new Employee(User_ID_List[i], User_name_List[i]),

Answer (score 0):

Finally got answer

```
            List<Employee> DVDList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

            while (rs.next()) {

                int_EMP_ID = rs.getInt("EmpID");
                str_EMP_Name = rs.getString("EmployeeName");

                int i = rs.getInt("EmpID");
                String s = rs.getString("EmployeeName");
                Employee context = new Employee(int_EMP_ID, str_EMP_Name);
                context.setEMPId(i);
                context.setEmpName(s);
                DVDList.add(context);

            }
            
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, DVDList);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```